# electron.atom.io and shared memory

Tags: shared-memory, electron

I would like to use Electron to build a Windows gui for a desktop app that shows images acquired in another desktop process (i.e. 25 megapixel image size).
The image data can be stored is a shared memory
Can I access the shared memory from the electron render process?
If I access from the electron main process, I read that the ipc between main/render processes is not suited to transfer such amount of data.

Comment: Are you showing images so rapidly that you really need shared memory? You might be able to do what you need with a temporary file. If you do use shared memory, you'll most likely need native code, which makes your app less portable.

Answer (score -2):

Electron render processes have full acess to all of node. If you can access what you need with a node module then you can easily display it in the same Electron render process.